# How do I scroll the inventory right in the book store?

Tags: pixel-piracy

Some of the book store items in the higher level towns are off the screen to the right, so I can't see the full description of the items for sale.  Is this a bug, or is there a key to scroll the shop inventory to the right?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug indeed, or a severe usability issue. I found that by hovering the mouse cursor over the buttons at the top (buy/sell), sometimes the scrollbar appears.